# PDFs are missing images when compiling knitr .RNW examples

Tags: r, pdf, latex, knitr, rstudio

I'm new to creating documents with knitr and Latex and I'm slowly being driven insane trying to figure out why the images of plots are missing from compiled pdfs.

For example, if I open the knitr minimal example that comes with the knitr package (v1.5) (stored in local R install directory `.... \library\knitr\examples\knitr-minimal.Rnw`) and compile it from within RStudio (version 0.98.490), I get a pdf file ([saved here](http://paulraftery.com/blog/wp-content/uploads/2013/12/knitr-minimal.pdf)) that is missing the example images but otherwise correct.

Any ideas where I can look to track down what's causing this problem?

Session Info

```
> R version 3.0.2 (2013-09-25)
> Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
> 
> locale:
> (1) LC_COLLATE=English_Ireland.1252  LC_CTYPE=English_Ireland.1252   
> (3) LC_MONETARY=English_Ireland.1252 LC_NUMERIC=C                    
> (5) LC_TIME=English_Ireland.1252    
> 
> attached base packages:
> (1) stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     
> 
> loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
> (1) tools_3.0.2
```

Output from compiling the pdf in RStudio:

```
> grDevices::pdf.options(useDingbats = FALSE); utils::Sweave('knitr-minimal.Rnw', encoding='ISO8859-1')
>Writing to file knitr-minimal.tex
>Processing code chunks with options ...
> 1 : echo keep.source term verbatim (label = setup, knitr-minimal.Rnw:21)
> 2 : echo keep.source term verbatim (label = boring-random, knitr-minimal.Rnw:38)
> 3 : echo keep.source term verbatim (label = boring-plots, knitr-minimal.Rnw:47)
>
>You can now run (pdf)latex on 'knitr-minimal.tex'
>
>
>Running pdflatex.exe on knitr-minimal.tex...completed
>
>Created PDF: C:/Program Files/R/R-3.0.2/library/knitr/examples/knitr-minimal.pdf
>
>Issues: 1 warning
```

Horrendously long Latex Compilation Log

```
>This is pdfTeX, Version 3.1415926-2.4-1.40.13 (MiKTeX 2.9 64-bit) (preloaded format=pdflatex 2013.12.21)  21 DEC 2013 05:24
>entering extended mode
>**knitr-minimal.tex
>("C:\Program Files\R\R-3.0.2\library\knitr\examples\knitr-minimal.tex"
>LaTeX2e <2011/06/27>
>Babel <v3.8m> and hyphenation patterns for english, afrikaans, ancientgreek, ar
>abic, armenian, assamese, basque, bengali, bokmal, bulgarian, catalan, coptic, 
>croatian, czech, danish, dutch, esperanto, estonian, farsi, finnish, french, ga
>lician, german, german-x-2012-05-30, greek, gujarati, hindi, hungarian, iceland
>ic, indonesian, interlingua, irish, italian, kannada, kurmanji, latin, latvian,
> lithuanian, malayalam, marathi, mongolian, mongolianlmc, monogreek, ngerman, n
>german-x-2012-05-30, nynorsk, oriya, panjabi, pinyin, polish, portuguese, roman
>ian, russian, sanskrit, serbian, slovak, slovenian, spanish, swedish, swissgerm
>an, tamil, telugu, turkish, turkmen, ukenglish, ukrainian, uppersorbian, usengl
>ishmax, welsh, loaded.
>("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\base\article.cls"
>Document Class: article 2007/10/19 v1.4h Standard LaTeX document class
>("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\base\size10.clo"
>File: size10.clo 2007/10/19 v1.4h Standard LaTeX file (size option)
>)
>\c@part=\count79
>\c@section=\count80
>\c@subsection=\count81
>\c@subsubsection=\count82
>\c@paragraph=\count83
>\c@subparagraph=\count84
>\c@figure=\count85
>\c@table=\count86
>\abovecaptionskip=\skip41
>\belowcaptionskip=\skip42
>\bibindent=\dimen102
>)
>("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\psnfss\mathpazo.sty"
>Package: mathpazo 2005/04/12 PSNFSS-v9.2a Palatino w/ Pazo Math (D.Puga, WaS) 
>\symupright=\mathgroup4
>)
>("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\base\fontenc.sty"
>Package: fontenc 2005/09/27 v1.99g Standard LaTeX package
>
>("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\base\t1enc.def"
>File: t1enc.def 2005/09/27 v1.99g Standard LaTeX file
>LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring font encoding T1 on input line 43.
>))
>("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\geometry\geometry.sty"
>Package: geometry 2010/09/12 v5.6 Page Geometry
>
>("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\graphics\keyval.sty"
>Package: keyval 1999/03/16 v1.13 key=value parser (DPC)
>\KV@toks@=\toks14
>)
>("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\oberdiek\ifpdf.sty"
>Package: ifpdf 2011/01/30 v2.3 Provides the ifpdf switch (HO)
>Package ifpdf Info: pdfTeX in PDF mode is detected.
>)
>("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\oberdiek\ifvtex.sty"
>Package: ifvtex 2010/03/01 v1.5 Detect VTeX and its facilities (HO)
>Package ifvtex Info: VTeX not detected.
>)
>("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\ifxetex\ifxetex.sty"
>Package: ifxetex 2010/09/12 v0.6 Provides ifxetex conditional
>)
>\Gm@cnth=\count87
>\Gm@cntv=\count88
>\c@Gm@tempcnt=\count89
>\Gm@bindingoffset=\dimen103
>\Gm@wd@mp=\dimen104
>\Gm@odd@mp=\dimen105
>\Gm@even@mp=\dimen106
>\Gm@layoutwidth=\dimen107
>\Gm@layoutheight=\dimen108
>\Gm@layouthoffset=\dimen109
>\Gm@layoutvoffset=\dimen110
>\Gm@dimlist=\toks15
>
>("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\geometry\geometry.cfg"))
>("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\ltxmisc\url.sty"
>\Urlmuskip=\muskip10
>Package: url 2006/04/12  ver 3.3  Verb mode for urls, etc.
>)
>("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\hyperref\hyperref.sty"
>Package: hyperref 2012/11/06 v6.83m Hypertext links for LaTeX
>
>("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\oberdiek\hobsub-hyperref.sty"
>Package: hobsub-hyperref 2012/04/25 v1.12 Bundle oberdiek, subset hyperref (HO)
>
>
>("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\oberdiek\hobsub-generic.sty"
>Package: hobsub-generic 2012/04/25 v1.12 Bundle oberdiek, subset generic (HO)
>Package: hobsub 2012/04/25 v1.12 Construct package bundles (HO)
>Package: infwarerr 2010/04/08 v1.3 Providing info/warning/error messages (HO)
>Package: ltxcmds 2011/11/09 v1.22 LaTeX kernel commands for general use (HO)
>Package: ifluatex 2010/03/01 v1.3 Provides the ifluatex switch (HO)
>Package ifluatex Info: LuaTeX not detected.
>Package hobsub Info: Skipping package `ifvtex' (already loaded).
>Package: intcalc 2007/09/27 v1.1 Expandable calculations with integers (HO)
>Package hobsub Info: Skipping package `ifpdf' (already loaded).
>Package: etexcmds 2011/02/16 v1.5 Avoid name clashes with e-TeX commands (HO)
>Package etexcmds Info: Could not find \expanded.
>(etexcmds)             That can mean that you are not using pdfTeX 1.50 or
>(etexcmds)             that some package has redefined \expanded.
>(etexcmds)             In the latter case, load this package earlier.
>Package: kvsetkeys 2012/04/25 v1.16 Key value parser (HO)
>Package: kvdefinekeys 2011/04/07 v1.3 Define keys (HO)
>Package: pdftexcmds 2011/11/29 v0.20 Utility functions of pdfTeX for LuaTeX (HO
>)
>Package pdftexcmds Info: LuaTeX not detected.
>Package pdftexcmds Info: \pdf@primitive is available.
>Package pdftexcmds Info: \pdf@ifprimitive is available.
>Package pdftexcmds Info: \pdfdraftmode found.
>Package: pdfescape 2011/11/25 v1.13 Implements pdfTeX's escape features (HO)
>Package: bigintcalc 2012/04/08 v1.3 Expandable calculations on big integers (HO
>)
>Package: bitset 2011/01/30 v1.1 Handle bit-vector datatype (HO)
>Package: uniquecounter 2011/01/30 v1.2 Provide unlimited unique counter (HO)
>)
>Package hobsub Info: Skipping package `hobsub' (already loaded).
>Package: letltxmacro 2010/09/02 v1.4 Let assignment for LaTeX macros (HO)
>Package: hopatch 2011/06/24 v1.1 Wrapper for package hooks (HO)
>Package: xcolor-patch 2011/01/30 xcolor patch
>Package: atveryend 2011/06/30 v1.8 Hooks at the very end of document (HO)
>Package atveryend Info: \enddocument detected (standard20110627).
>Package: atbegshi 2011/10/05 v1.16 At begin shipout hook (HO)
>Package: refcount 2011/10/16 v3.4 Data extraction from label references (HO)
>Package: hycolor 2011/01/30 v1.7 Color options for hyperref/bookmark (HO)
>)
>("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\oberdiek\auxhook.sty"
>Package: auxhook 2011/03/04 v1.3 Hooks for auxiliary files (HO)
>)
>("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\oberdiek\kvoptions.sty"
>Package: kvoptions 2011/06/30 v3.11 Key value format for package options (HO)
>)
>\@linkdim=\dimen111
>\Hy@linkcounter=\count90
>\Hy@pagecounter=\count91
>
>("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\hyperref\pd1enc.def"
>File: pd1enc.def 2012/11/06 v6.83m Hyperref: PDFDocEncoding definition (HO)
>)
>\Hy@SavedSpaceFactor=\count92
>
>("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\00miktex\hyperref.cfg"
>File: hyperref.cfg 2002/06/06 v1.2 hyperref configuration of TeXLive
>)
>Package hyperref Info: Option `unicode' set `true' on input line 4319.
>
>("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\hyperref\puenc.def"
>File: puenc.def 2012/11/06 v6.83m Hyperref: PDF Unicode definition (HO)
>)
>Package hyperref Info: Option `pdfusetitle' set `true' on input line 4319.
>Package hyperref Info: Option `bookmarks' set `true' on input line 4319.
>Package hyperref Info: Option `bookmarksnumbered' set `true' on input line 4319
>.
>Package hyperref Info: Option `bookmarksopen' set `true' on input line 4319.
>Package hyperref Info: Option `breaklinks' set `false' on input line 4319.
>Package hyperref Info: Option `colorlinks' set `false' on input line 4319.
>Package hyperref Info: Hyper figures OFF on input line 4443.
>Package hyperref Info: Link nesting OFF on input line 4448.
>Package hyperref Info: Hyper index ON on input line 4451.
>Package hyperref Info: Plain pages OFF on input line 4458.
>Package hyperref Info: Backreferencing OFF on input line 4463.
>Package hyperref Info: Implicit mode ON; LaTeX internals redefined.
>Package hyperref Info: Bookmarks ON on input line 4688.
>\c@Hy@tempcnt=\count93
>LaTeX Info: Redefining \url on input line 5041.
>\XeTeXLinkMargin=\dimen112
>\Fld@menulength=\count94
>\Field@Width=\dimen113
>\Fld@charsize=\dimen114
>Package hyperref Info: Hyper figures OFF on input line 6295.
>Package hyperref Info: Link nesting OFF on input line 6300.
>Package hyperref Info: Hyper index ON on input line 6303.
>Package hyperref Info: backreferencing OFF on input line 6310.
>Package hyperref Info: Link coloring OFF on input line 6315.
>Package hyperref Info: Link coloring with OCG OFF on input line 6320.
>Package hyperref Info: PDF/A mode OFF on input line 6325.
>LaTeX Info: Redefining \ref on input line 6365.
>LaTeX Info: Redefining \pageref on input line 6369.
>\Hy@abspage=\count95
>\c@Item=\count96
>\c@Hfootnote=\count97
>)
>
>Package hyperref Message: Driver (autodetected): hpdftex.
>
>("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\hyperref\hpdftex.def"
>File: hpdftex.def 2012/11/06 v6.83m Hyperref driver for pdfTeX
>\Fld@listcount=\count98
>\c@bookmark@seq@number=\count99
>
>("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\oberdiek\rerunfilecheck.sty"
>Package: rerunfilecheck 2011/04/15 v1.7 Rerun checks for auxiliary files (HO)
>Package uniquecounter Info: New unique counter `rerunfilecheck' on input line 2
>82.
>)
>\Hy@SectionHShift=\skip43
>)
>("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\breakurl\breakurl.sty"
>Package: breakurl 2013/04/10 v1.40 Breakable hyperref URLs
>
>("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\xkeyval\xkeyval.sty"
>Package: xkeyval 2012/10/14 v2.6b package option processing (HA)
>
>("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\xkeyval\xkeyval.tex"
>\XKV@toks=\toks16
>\XKV@tempa@toks=\toks17
>\XKV@depth=\count100
>File: xkeyval.tex 2012/10/14 v2.6b key=value parser (HA)
>))
>
>Package breakurl Warning: You are using breakurl while processing via pdflatex.
>
>(breakurl)                \burl will be just a synonym of \url.
>(breakurl)                 on input line 48.
>
>) (C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-30~1.2/share/texmf/tex/latex\Sweave.sty
>Package: Sweave 
>
>("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\base\ifthen.sty"
>Package: ifthen 2001/05/26 v1.1c Standard LaTeX ifthen package (DPC)
>)
>("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\graphics\graphicx.sty"
>Package: graphicx 1999/02/16 v1.0f Enhanced LaTeX Graphics (DPC,SPQR)
>
>("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\graphics\graphics.sty"
>Package: graphics 2009/02/05 v1.0o Standard LaTeX Graphics (DPC,SPQR)
>
>("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\graphics\trig.sty"
>Package: trig 1999/03/16 v1.09 sin cos tan (DPC)
>)
>("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\00miktex\graphics.cfg"
>File: graphics.cfg 2007/01/18 v1.5 graphics configuration of teTeX/TeXLive
>)
>Package graphics Info: Driver file: pdftex.def on input line 91.
>
>("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\pdftex-def\pdftex.def"
>File: pdftex.def 2011/05/27 v0.06d Graphics/color for pdfTeX
>\Gread@gobject=\count101
>))
>\Gin@req@height=\dimen115
>\Gin@req@width=\dimen116
>)
>("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\fancyvrb\fancyvrb.sty"
>Package: fancyvrb 2008/02/07
>
>Style option: `fancyvrb' v2.7a, with DG/SPQR fixes, and firstline=lastline fix 
><2008/02/07> (tvz)
>\FV@CodeLineNo=\count102
>\FV@InFile=\read1
>\FV@TabBox=\box26
>\c@FancyVerbLine=\count103
>\FV@StepNumber=\count104
>\FV@OutFile=\write3
>) ("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\base\textcomp.sty"
>Package: textcomp 2005/09/27 v1.99g Standard LaTeX package
>Package textcomp Info: Sub-encoding information:
>(textcomp)               5 = only ISO-Adobe without \textcurrency
>(textcomp)               4 = 5 + \texteuro
>(textcomp)               3 = 4 + \textohm
>(textcomp)               2 = 3 + \textestimated + \textcurrency
>(textcomp)               1 = TS1 - \textcircled - \t
>(textcomp)               0 = TS1 (full)
>(textcomp)             Font families with sub-encoding setting implement
>(textcomp)             only a restricted character set as indicated.
>(textcomp)             Family '?' is the default used for unknown fonts.
>(textcomp)             See the documentation for details.
>Package textcomp Info: Setting ? sub-encoding to TS1/1 on input line 71.
>
>("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\base\ts1enc.def"
>File: ts1enc.def 2001/06/05 v3.0e (jk/car/fm) Standard LaTeX file
>)
>LaTeX Info: Redefining \oldstylenums on input line 266.
>Package textcomp Info: Setting cmr sub-encoding to TS1/0 on input line 281.
>Package textcomp Info: Setting cmss sub-encoding to TS1/0 on input line 282.
>Package textcomp Info: Setting cmtt sub-encoding to TS1/0 on input line 283.
>Package textcomp Info: Setting cmvtt sub-encoding to TS1/0 on input line 284.
>Package textcomp Info: Setting cmbr sub-encoding to TS1/0 on input line 285.
>Package textcomp Info: Setting cmtl sub-encoding to TS1/0 on input line 286.
>Package textcomp Info: Setting ccr sub-encoding to TS1/0 on input line 287.
>Package textcomp Info: Setting ptm sub-encoding to TS1/4 on input line 288.
>Package textcomp Info: Setting pcr sub-encoding to TS1/4 on input line 289.
>Package textcomp Info: Setting phv sub-encoding to TS1/4 on input line 290.
>Package textcomp Info: Setting ppl sub-encoding to TS1/3 on input line 291.
>Package textcomp Info: Setting pag sub-encoding to TS1/4 on input line 292.
>Package textcomp Info: Setting pbk sub-encoding to TS1/4 on input line 293.
>Package textcomp Info: Setting pnc sub-encoding to TS1/4 on input line 294.
>Package textcomp Info: Setting pzc sub-encoding to TS1/4 on input line 295.
>Package textcomp Info: Setting bch sub-encoding to TS1/4 on input line 296.
>Package textcomp Info: Setting put sub-encoding to TS1/5 on input line 297.
>Package textcomp Info: Setting uag sub-encoding to TS1/5 on input line 298.
>Package textcomp Info: Setting ugq sub-encoding to TS1/5 on input line 299.
>Package textcomp Info: Setting ul8 sub-encoding to TS1/4 on input line 300.
>Package textcomp Info: Setting ul9 sub-encoding to TS1/4 on input line 301.
>Package textcomp Info: Setting augie sub-encoding to TS1/5 on input line 302.
>Package textcomp Info: Setting dayrom sub-encoding to TS1/3 on input line 303.
>Package textcomp Info: Setting dayroms sub-encoding to TS1/3 on input line 304.
>
>Package textcomp Info: Setting pxr sub-encoding to TS1/0 on input line 305.
>Package textcomp Info: Setting pxss sub-encoding to TS1/0 on input line 306.
>Package textcomp Info: Setting pxtt sub-encoding to TS1/0 on input line 307.
>Package textcomp Info: Setting txr sub-encoding to TS1/0 on input line 308.
>Package textcomp Info: Setting txss sub-encoding to TS1/0 on input line 309.
>Package textcomp Info: Setting txtt sub-encoding to TS1/0 on input line 310.
>Package textcomp Info: Setting lmr sub-encoding to TS1/0 on input line 311.
>Package textcomp Info: Setting lmdh sub-encoding to TS1/0 on input line 312.
>Package textcomp Info: Setting lmss sub-encoding to TS1/0 on input line 313.
>Package textcomp Info: Setting lmssq sub-encoding to TS1/0 on input line 314.
>Package textcomp Info: Setting lmvtt sub-encoding to TS1/0 on input line 315.
>Package textcomp Info: Setting qhv sub-encoding to TS1/0 on input line 316.
>Package textcomp Info: Setting qag sub-encoding to TS1/0 on input line 317.
>Package textcomp Info: Setting qbk sub-encoding to TS1/0 on input line 318.
>Package textcomp Info: Setting qcr sub-encoding to TS1/0 on input line 319.
>Package textcomp Info: Setting qcs sub-encoding to TS1/0 on input line 320.
>Package textcomp Info: Setting qpl sub-encoding to TS1/0 on input line 321.
>Package textcomp Info: Setting qtm sub-encoding to TS1/0 on input line 322.
>Package textcomp Info: Setting qzc sub-encoding to TS1/0 on input line 323.
>Package textcomp Info: Setting qhvc sub-encoding to TS1/0 on input line 324.
>Package textcomp Info: Setting futs sub-encoding to TS1/4 on input line 325.
>Package textcomp Info: Setting futx sub-encoding to TS1/4 on input line 326.
>Package textcomp Info: Setting futj sub-encoding to TS1/4 on input line 327.
>Package textcomp Info: Setting hlh sub-encoding to TS1/3 on input line 328.
>Package textcomp Info: Setting hls sub-encoding to TS1/3 on input line 329.
>Package textcomp Info: Setting hlst sub-encoding to TS1/3 on input line 330.
>Package textcomp Info: Setting hlct sub-encoding to TS1/5 on input line 331.
>Package textcomp Info: Setting hlx sub-encoding to TS1/5 on input line 332.
>Package textcomp Info: Setting hlce sub-encoding to TS1/5 on input line 333.
>Package textcomp Info: Setting hlcn sub-encoding to TS1/5 on input line 334.
>Package textcomp Info: Setting hlcw sub-encoding to TS1/5 on input line 335.
>Package textcomp Info: Setting hlcf sub-encoding to TS1/5 on input line 336.
>Package textcomp Info: Setting pplx sub-encoding to TS1/3 on input line 337.
>Package textcomp Info: Setting pplj sub-encoding to TS1/3 on input line 338.
>Package textcomp Info: Setting ptmx sub-encoding to TS1/4 on input line 339.
>Package textcomp Info: Setting ptmj sub-encoding to TS1/4 on input line 340.
>)
>("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\base\fontenc.sty"
>Package: fontenc 2005/09/27 v1.99g Standard LaTeX package
>
>("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\base\t1enc.def"
>File: t1enc.def 2005/09/27 v1.99g Standard LaTeX file
>LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring font encoding T1 on input line 43.
>))
>("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\ae\ae.sty"
>Package: ae 2001/02/12 1.3 Almost European Computer Modern
>
>("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\base\fontenc.sty"
>Package: fontenc 2005/09/27 v1.99g Standard LaTeX package
>
>("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\base\t1enc.def"
>File: t1enc.def 2005/09/27 v1.99g Standard LaTeX file
>LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring font encoding T1 on input line 43.
>)
>LaTeX Font Info:    Try loading font information for T1+aer on input line 100.
>
>("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\ae\t1aer.fd"
>File: t1aer.fd 1997/11/16 Font definitions for T1/aer.
>))))
>("C:\Program Files\R\R-3.0.2\library\knitr\examples\knitr-minimal.aux")
>LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OML/cmm/m/it on input line 19.
>LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 19.
>LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for T1/cmr/m/n on input line 19.
>LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 19.
>LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OT1/cmr/m/n on input line 19.
>LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 19.
>LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OMS/cmsy/m/n on input line 19.
>LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 19.
>LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OMX/cmex/m/n on input line 19.
>LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 19.
>LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for U/cmr/m/n on input line 19.
>LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 19.
>LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for PD1/pdf/m/n on input line 19.
>LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 19.
>LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for PU/pdf/m/n on input line 19.
>LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 19.
>LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for TS1/cmr/m/n on input line 19.
>LaTeX Font Info:    Try loading font information for TS1+cmr on input line 19.
>
>("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\base\ts1cmr.fd"
>File: ts1cmr.fd 1999/05/25 v2.5h Standard LaTeX font definitions
>)
>LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 19.
>\big@size=\dimen117
>
>*geometry* driver: auto-detecting
>*geometry* detected driver: pdftex
>
>Package geometry Warning: The marginal notes overrun the paper.
>     Add 4.86812pt and more to the right margin.
>
>*geometry* verbose mode - [ preamble ] result:
>* driver: pdftex
>* paper: <default>
>* layout: <same size as paper>
>* layoutoffset:(h,v)=(0.0pt,0.0pt)
>* modes: 
>* h-part:(L,W,R)=(71.13188pt, 472.03123pt, 71.13188pt)
>* v-part:(T,H,B)=(71.13188pt, 652.70622pt, 71.13188pt)
>* \paperwidth=614.295pt
>* \paperheight=794.96999pt
>* \textwidth=472.03123pt
>* \textheight=652.70622pt
>* \oddsidemargin=-1.1381pt
>* \evensidemargin=-1.1381pt
>* \topmargin=-38.1381pt
>* \headheight=12.0pt
>* \headsep=25.0pt
>* \topskip=10.0pt
>* \footskip=30.0pt
>* \marginparwidth=65.0pt
>* \marginparsep=11.0pt
>* \columnsep=10.0pt
>* \skip\footins=9.0pt plus 4.0pt minus 2.0pt
>* \hoffset=0.0pt
>* \voffset=0.0pt
>* \mag=1000
>* \@twocolumnfalse
>* \@twosidefalse
>* \@mparswitchfalse
>* \@reversemarginfalse
>* (1in=72.27pt=25.4mm, 1cm=28.453pt)
>
>\AtBeginShipoutBox=\box27
>Package hyperref Info: Link coloring OFF on input line 19.
>("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\hyperref\nameref.sty"
>Package: nameref 2012/10/27 v2.43 Cross-referencing by name of section
>
>("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\oberdiek\gettitlestring.sty"
>Package: gettitlestring 2010/12/03 v1.4 Cleanup title references (HO)
>)
>\c@section@level=\count105
>)
>LaTeX Info: Redefining \ref on input line 19.
>LaTeX Info: Redefining \pageref on input line 19.
>LaTeX Info: Redefining \nameref on input line 19.
>
>("C:\Program Files\R\R-3.0.2\library\knitr\examples\knitr-minimal.out")
>("C:\Program Files\R\R-3.0.2\library\knitr\examples\knitr-minimal.out")
>\@outlinefile=\write4
>
>("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\context\base\supp-pdf.mkii"
>[Loading MPS to PDF converter (version 2006.09.02).]
>\scratchcounter=\count106
>\scratchdimen=\dimen118
>\scratchbox=\box28
>\nofMPsegments=\count107
>\nofMParguments=\count108
>\everyMPshowfont=\toks18
>\MPscratchCnt=\count109
>\MPscratchDim=\dimen119
>\MPnumerator=\count110
>\makeMPintoPDFobject=\count111
>\everyMPtoPDFconversion=\toks19
>)
>("C:\Program Files\R\R-3.0.2\library\knitr\examples\knitr-minimal-concordance.t
>ex")
>LaTeX Font Info:    Try loading font information for T1+aett on input line 23.
> ("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\ae\t1aett.fd"
>File: t1aett.fd 1997/11/16 Font definitions for T1/aett.
>)
>LaTeX Font Info:    Try loading font information for TS1+aett on input line 26.
>
>
>(C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-30~1.2/share/texmf/tex/latex\ts1aett.fd
>File: ts1aett.fd 
>)
>LaTeX Font Info:    Try loading font information for TS1+cmtt on input line 26.
>
>
>("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\base\ts1cmtt.fd"
>File: ts1cmtt.fd 1999/05/25 v2.5h Standard LaTeX font definitions
>)
>LaTeX Font Info:    Font shape `TS1/aett/m/sl' in size <10> not available
>(Font)              Font shape `TS1/cmtt/m/sl' tried instead on input line 26.
> [1
>
>{C:/ProgramData/MiKTeX/2.9/pdftex/config/pdftex.map}]
>LaTeX Font Info:    Try loading font information for OT1+pplx on input line 38.
>
>
>("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\psnfss\ot1pplx.fd"
>File: ot1pplx.fd 2004/09/06 font definitions for OT1/pplx.
>)
>LaTeX Font Info:    Try loading font information for OML+zplm on input line 38.
>
>
>("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\psnfss\omlzplm.fd"
>File: omlzplm.fd 2002/09/08 Fontinst v1.914 font definitions for OML/zplm.
>)
>LaTeX Font Info:    Try loading font information for OMS+zplm on input line 38.
>
>
>("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\psnfss\omszplm.fd"
>File: omszplm.fd 2002/09/08 Fontinst v1.914 font definitions for OMS/zplm.
>)
>LaTeX Font Info:    Try loading font information for OMX+zplm on input line 38.
>
>
>("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\psnfss\omxzplm.fd"
>File: omxzplm.fd 2002/09/08 Fontinst v1.914 font definitions for OMX/zplm.
>)
>LaTeX Font Info:    Try loading font information for OT1+zplm on input line 38.
>
>
>("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\psnfss\ot1zplm.fd"
>File: ot1zplm.fd 2002/09/08 Fontinst v1.914 font definitions for OT1/zplm.
>)
>Package atveryend Info: Empty hook `BeforeClearDocument' on input line 84.
> [2]
>Package atveryend Info: Empty hook `AfterLastShipout' on input line 84.
>
>("C:\Program Files\R\R-3.0.2\library\knitr\examples\knitr-minimal.aux")
>Package atveryend Info: Executing hook `AtVeryEndDocument' on input line 84.
>Package atveryend Info: Executing hook `AtEndAfterFileList' on input line 84.
>Package rerunfilecheck Info: File `knitr-minimal.out' has not changed.
>(rerunfilecheck)             Checksum: D41D8CD98F00B204E9800998ECF8427E;0.
>Package atveryend Info: Empty hook `AtVeryVeryEnd' on input line 84.
> ) 
>Here is how much of TeX's memory you used:
> 10040 strings out of 493921
> 143131 string characters out of 3147284
> 202058 words of memory out of 3000000
> 13216 multiletter control sequences out of 15000+200000
> 29465 words of font info for 72 fonts, out of 3000000 for 9000
> 841 hyphenation exceptions out of 8191
> 35i,6n,35p,227b,358s stack positions out of 5000i,500n,10000p,200000b,50000s
> <C:\Users\Paul\AppData\Local\MiKTeX\2.9\fonts\pk\ljfour\jknappen\ec\dpi600\t
>cst1000.pk><C:/Program Files/MiKTeX 2.9/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/cm/cmbx10.p
>fb><C:/Program Files/MiKTeX 2.9/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/cm/cmr10.pfb><C:/Pr
>ogram Files/MiKTeX 2.9/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/cm/cmr12.pfb><C:/Program Fil
>es/MiKTeX 2.9/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/cm/cmr17.pfb><C:/Program Files/MiKTeX
> 2.9/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/cm/cmsltt10.pfb><C:/Program Files/MiKTeX 2.9/f
>onts/type1/public/amsfonts/cm/cmtt10.pfb>
>Output written on knitr-minimal.pdf (2 pages, 88102 bytes).
>PDF statistics:
> 47 PDF objects out of 1000 (max. 8388607)
> 3 named destinations out of 1000 (max. 500000)
> 5 words of extra memory for PDF output out of 10000 (max. 10000000)
>
>
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In RStudio, the default weave option needs to be changed from Sweave to knitr. In Windows 7, I select the Tools tab, global options tab, Sweave tab, and then change "Sweave" defalut to "knitr".

Comment: Thank you. Such a simple thing... you have no idea how frustrated I was with this yesterday! Thanks again.